# Getting unexpected behavior with multiple OR conditions

Tags: pyspark

Here is my code:

```
df.where((F.col("A") != F.col("B")) | \
         (F.col("A").isNotNull()) | \
         (F.col("C") == F.col("D"))).show()
```

When I do this, I do see instances that contradict some of the conditions above. Now, when I structure the code like this, it runs successfully:

```
df.where((F.col("A") != F.col("B")))\
  .where((F.col("A").isNotNull()))\
  .where((F.col("C") == F.col("D")))
```

Answer (score 1):

The first snipper uses the `|` to combine the three conditions.However, the `|` checks if any of the conditions evaluate to true rather than all of them.

However, chaining using `where` clause is equivalent to combining the conditions using `and`.
Hence, the snippets in the code are not equivalent and produce different results.

For equivalence, you first snipper will become

```
df.where((F.col("A") != F.col("B")) & \
         (F.col("A").isNotNull()) & \
         (F.col("C") == F.col("D"))).show()
```